# How does including the header automatically define the class in to the driver (main)?

Tags: c++, header

I'm a noob to C++ and mainly used scripting languages like python to get by. Compiling languages are new to me and I am having a hard time understanding `#include`, headers, and so on.

I was recently trying to write a program with a class, called `Point.cpp`. So, I tried including this class into my main file by `#include "Point.cpp"`. This prompted an error saying that the constructors were defined multiple times. A StackExchange post addressed a similar problem and advised to include the header instead. This time the code compiled without a problem and worked as expected.

It seems strange that this would work because I have already included  `"Point.hh"` into `Point.cpp`, so it seemed logical (transitive) to include `Point.cpp` into `main.cpp`.

Can someone weigh in on this? I would like to understand this better. Thanks.

Comment: The header file doesn't contain the _definition_ of the class, but it's _declaration_. The latter contains all the information compiler needs, that the class can be used properly in any translation unit.

Comment: Never include .cpp file (If you want to anyway, rename it as a header). Your IDE usualy compiles *.cpp and then links those together. So, if you include it as cpp, it will be in your program executable twice.

Comment: @krOoze _"If you want to anyway, rename it as a header"_ That's particularly answered and relevant here: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)